# How to get list item in SharePoint using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I used this synthax to get list Items

```
http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

I get a list repeating today's date but not items .

EDIT: I notice that the number of lines that the REST Query print is equal to the number of elements in the list

[image: list of dates image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in your Browser setting Please follow below steps you get the desired data
In Internet Explorer

->Open Tools->Internet Options

->Select the Content tab Click the “Settings” button in the Feed and Web slices section

->Uncheck Turn on feed reading view

->Click “OK” to save the settings

And for Firefox

With your output on firefox use **ctrl + u** will convert it xml format but not readable as IE you can copy the output in notepad as .xml and open it with Office XMl handler.

Comment: I can't find that. I'm using FireFox

Comment: Hope this link may help with the settings http://superuser.com/questions/81892/how-to-reset-firefox-rss-feed-handling

Comment: If not then no clue try using IE

Comment: ctrl+u has done the job. it's a shortcut for what ?

Comment: Its a shortcut to ->viewsource:'url' of a web feed

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this url

```
http://server/site/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

Comment: I get same result by adding /web.
I want to precise that I'm putting the link to the web navigator directly not in a script.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `web` in URL. It should be :

```
 http://server/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

Comment: I have added a comment to Suresh Bolineni