# When using API request in SharePoint Online I get date et not list names

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, api

When I use `_api/lists` in order to get lists of my SharePoint, I get list of date like this.

```
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
mercredi 3 mai 2017 10:14
```

Is it normal ?

this is the url that I typed in Url bar :

```
https://[domain].sharepoint.com/sites/[sitename]/_api/Web/Lists/
```

Comment: How does your API request look like?

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried to achieve. So one can understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Its not the problem of the rest query it is the browser setting which you have to change you have to disable web feeds for xml data response for the browser
[you can refer my answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209433/how-to-get-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api/209443#209443)

And you should specify web in your query as suggested by MILAD

Answer (score 0):

It should look like

```
yourdomin.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecoll/_api/Web/Lists
```